# My Game stopped working after upgrading To Xcode 8

Tags: swift, xcode8

I'm new with Swift. Before the new IOS release my game was working in Apple store. Now It can successfully build but it fail when I click on the Start button. 
I couldn't find anything wrong with my code.

Please check the exception below:-

exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'SKAction animateWithTextures: textures array cannot be empty'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109cca34b **exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001093c521e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109d33265 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   SpriteKit                           0x000000010a7e1f81 +[SKAnimate animateWithTextures:timePerFrame:resize:restore:] + 120
    4   SpriteKit                           0x000000010a7ddd71 +[SKAction(SKActions) animateWithTextures:timePerFrame:] + 29
    5   TwistyPlane                         0x0000000108dc3aea _TFC11TwistyPlane9GameScenecfT5coderCSo7NSCoder_GSqS0** + 906
    6   TwistyPlane                         0x0000000108dc3c0d _TToFC11TwistyPlane9GameScenecfT5coderCSo7NSCoder_GSqS0__ + 45
    7   Foundation                          0x0000000108e95f12 _decodeObjectBinary + 2622
    8   Foundation                          0x0000000108e953c6 _decodeObject + 249
    9   SpriteKit                           0x000000010a84126b +[SKNode nodeWithFileNamed:] + 578
    10  TwistyPlane                         0x0000000108dc6fdd _TTOFCSo7SKSceneCfT9fileNamedSS_GSqS__ + 77
    11  TwistyPlane                         0x0000000108dc6d31 _TFC11TwistyPlane18GameViewController11viewDidLoadfT_T_ + 129
    12  TwistyPlane                         0x0000000108dc7032 _TToFC11TwistyPlane18GameViewController11viewDidLoadfT_T_ + 34
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010abcf06d -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1258
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010abcf4a0 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010b4938d0 -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _setPresentedViewController:] + 87
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010aba9d26 -[UIPresentationController initWithPresentedViewController:presentingViewController:] + 141
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010abe230b -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 3956
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010abe56df -[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:] + 530
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010abe51c5 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 179
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010abea892 -[UIViewController _showViewController:withAction:sender:] + 274
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010b0af1b6 **66-[UIStoryboardShowSegueTemplate newDefaultPerformHandlerForSegue:]_block_invoke + 134
    22  UIKit                               0x000000010b20840d -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _performWithDestinationViewController:sender:] + 447
    23  UIKit                               0x000000010b20821d -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 82
    24  UIKit                               0x000000010b2084df -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 156
    25  UIKit                               0x000000010aa2fb88 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    26  UIKit                               0x000000010abb52b2 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    27  UIKit                               0x000000010abb55cb -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 444
    28  UIKit                               0x000000010abb44c7 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 668
    29  UIKit                               0x000000010aa9d0d5 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2747
    30  UIKit                               0x000000010aa9e7c3 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4011
    31  UIKit                               0x000000010aa4ba33 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 371
    32  UIKit                               0x000000010b23db6d __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3248
    33  UIKit                               0x000000010b236817 __handleEventQueue + 4879
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109c6f311 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109c5459c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109c53a86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109c53494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    38  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010ff39a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    39  UIKit                               0x000000010aa2df34 UIApplicationMain + 159
    40  TwistyPlane                         0x0000000108dc956f main + 111
    41  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010dceb68d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: You're going to have to narrow this down more to try and help, the most I can tell from this is that it may be an issue with a call to animateWithTextures somewhere in your code. You need to debug your code to the last line before it breaks, double check to make sure theres no issues with what you see after and try posting it here again to see.

Comment: You need to format your code presentation.

Answer (score 1):

It says your error in the first line "SKAction animateWithTextures: textures array cannot be empty" check your code and ensure this complaint is satisfied. It appears as though you are either calling or using an empty array for calling data. And the program crashes because there's nothing to return. That's what I see.